# Axios url get reques to for html response is 200 but response.data is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

So i'm using this URL because i want so scrape html using axios and cheerio:
https://www.mgewholesale.com/ecommerce/Bags%20and%20Cases.cfm?cat_id=876

I tested a get request in postman and it works fine with status 200

using this code works with status 200 as well but response.data is empty

update, so with this code i got the actual response with the data object filled, but when im trying to access to response.data it shows me this error:

```
const axios = require('axios'); 
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const https = require('https');

let fs = require('fs');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });

axios
    .get('https://www.mgewholesale.com/ecommerce/Bags%20and%20Cases.cfm', {
        httpsAgent,
        params: {
            cat_id: '876',
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        },
        //is the same as set the entire url
    })
    .then((res) => {

        console.log(res.data)
        //this triggers the error

       // let status = res.status;
        console.log(status);
       //Status 200
       console.log(response)
        //This brings the entire response with data object filled

    });

ERROR:
(node:9068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
(node:9068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried using the entire url and the url with its params it brings me empty data, but if i try with other url like: https://www.google.com it brings me the actual html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your query params are not getting added on correctly.

Remove `+ '.json'` from the second argument of `axios.get`.

I'm surprised that this isn't throwing an error on its own, but apparently axios is just playing along and appending `0=[object+Object].json`, turning your URL into: `https://www.mgewholesale.com/ecommerce/Bags%20and%20Cases.cfm?0=[object+Object].json`

I can't add a comment to the other answer, but it is incorrect as you are properly using promise chaining ( `.then` ) after your call to `.get()`.

---

Edit:
For this particular URL, it looks like you will need some additional headers, as well as the ability to keep the connection alive after the initial response:

```js
const axios = require('axios'); //15k (gzipped: 5.1k)
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const https = require('https');

let fs = require('fs');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });

axios
    .get('https://www.mgewholesale.com/ecommerce/Bags%20and%20Cases.cfm', {
        httpsAgent,
        params: {
            cat_id: '876',
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        },
        //is the same as set the entire url
    })
    .then((res) => {
        let status = res.status;
        console.log(status);
        //This should now output the html content
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Edit 2:
Added the proper method for handling errors to the code above.

Edit 3:
Make sure the variables you are logging in your `.then()` block are all defined. Also, to get more helpful errors, add the `.catch()` to the end:

```js
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        //this triggers the error

        let status = res.status;
        console.log(status);
        //Status 200
        console.log(res);
        //This brings the entire response with data object filled
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I also tried with out the +'.json', i saw that solution in other post but it didnt work for me, i also tried putting the whole url together(with the parameters included)

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in your console like so:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.mgewholesale.com/ecommerce/Bags%20and%20Cases.cfm?cat_id=876' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Edit: Disregard as I now see you are using the from the server side. Nonetheless, it might be good to check your request headers for any sort of cross origin restrictions.

Comment: nope, as i said, in postman is working perfectly, but in axios its status 200 but empty response.data

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution. I was able to get this working locally.

Comment: +1 for the `accept-encoding: gzip` header being required by the website and keep-alive needing to be set

Comment: Hey! My answer was the accepted answer but is no longer. Can you please it as the accepted answer? @Chris

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but almost there. status:200, response actually shows the response.data in json, but when i want to use the data object shows me this error:

Comment: (node:9068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)

Comment: (node:9068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: (node:9068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code? @Chris

Comment: Thankyou! by the way, how did you realize that this specific url needed that headers?

Comment: @Chris In postman, I went to the `Headers` tab and clicked the button to show hidden headers (for me it had an eye icon with the label `8 hidden`). I then disabled all of the headers and played around with re-enabling various combinations until I found the minimum headers needed for the request to work.